# Error every time I start a new VS project "Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this project."

Tags: c++, project, spectre

Whenever I start a new C++ project on Visual Studio and compile, I am faced with this error. I then have to go to settings and disable spectre mitigation.

> Error MSB8040 Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this
> project. Install them from the Visual Studio installer (Individual
> components tab) for any toolsets and architectures being used. Learn
> more: https://aka.ms/Ofhn4c2_Beginner-IntermediateC++
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft
> VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets 428

Is there a way to have this option disabled automatically by default?

Why is this option enabled for me by default? I think I may have messed up an installation somewhere along the way as I don't see many posts about this online.

[What I have to do every time to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fauBH.png)

Note: I remember trying to install the libraries it's suggesting but there was around a dozen of them and they didn't seem to be making a difference. It was a long time ago though and I may have made a mistake. I will try again.

Comment: Did you try to install those libraries from the visual studio installer as stated in the message? Simply ignoring warnings is usually bad, because usually warninges appear for a reason. Spectre mitigation is enabled by default, because it's reasonable to use safe libraries by default and not unsafe ones.

Comment: Thanks churill, I didn't know it was enabled by default. Changes my approach to the problem :)

Comment: @churill `/Qspectre` should be [off by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/qspectre?view=vs-2019) in VC++ alone, though some external packages are known to change the default to on. @Eon Do you have the [WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) (1903 or earlier) installed by any chance?

Comment: @dxiv I have WDK 10.0.18466.1000 installed. Come to think of it I think it was around this time when I installed the WDK that this issue cropped up

Answer (score 2):

Ok thanks to @dxiv I managed to solve this issue, i.e. now my new C++ projects on Visual Studio have Spectre Mitigations OFF by default and I don't have to manually disable it every time I create a new project.

First I uninstalled WDK, it did not solve the issue.

Then on Visual Studio Installer > Modify > under Individual Components > Untick box that says WDK (3MB) > Modify. This will remove that WDK component. And now the spectre mitigation is off by default.

The solution could be due to both of the steps I mentioned but probably it was enough to just remove that component from Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: Or you could upgrade the WDK to the latest [version 2004](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/96c770a9-19a3-42d0-8d0e-bd200285d980/hardware-development-kits-for-windows-10-version-2004?forum=wdk): "*Installing WDK no longer enables Spectre mitigations for all C++ projects as seen in WDK 1903. While the WDK install will enable Spectre mitigation by default for all drivers, it no longer enables them for all C++ projects*".